# Destructors and maps

Tags: c++, destructor

```
class X;

class Y {
    public:
        ~Y();
    private:
        map<int,X*> m;
        vector<X*> v;
        X* px;
};
```

I guess the destructor for `class Y` should look something like this?

```
Y::~Y() {
    delete px; 
    for (vector<X*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); it++) 
    delete *it;
    v.clear();
}
```

But what about `Y::m`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for vector, but for map...

```
for (map<int, X*>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
   delete it->second;
```

Comment: @OP: pay attention to the preincrement. It is better to use preincrement with iterators as you see here

Comment: Oh, my... I haven't even thought that maps have iterators. Sorry for bothering. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Nope, that's completely wrong. You have manually deleted your resources instead of using a resource managing class. This is a very bad error. You really want `unique_ptr<X>` or `shared_ptr<X>` or some similar class, instead of `X*`, if you are responsible for freeing them.

```
class Y {
    private:
        map<int,std::unique_ptr<X>> m;
        vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> v;
        std::unique_ptr<X> px;
};
```

Now no custom destructor required.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but calling it completely wrong is wrong , though your advice is good +1 :)

Comment: I don't know, why the thumbs down, this is the definition of being constructive.

Comment: Any C++ code that uses owning raw pointers is completely wrong, unless for very good reasons.

Comment: It's the kind of wrong where it's perfectly sane and reasonable to always judge it wrong, unless a very convincing reason is given for a very small, specific exception. In the general case it is always wrong.

Comment: Is that wrong about not using C++11? I found that a valid piece of code.

Comment: C++11 makes it *easier* to do the right thing, but isn't fundamentally different about what's right and what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Same:

```
for (map<int,X*>::iterator it = m.begin() ; it != m.end() ; it++ )
   delete it->second;
```

In C++11 you can use `auto` to skip the iterator type.

There's also no need to call `v.clear();` in the destructor.